# Why is this verb written as "zeige" rather than "zeigt"? Konjunktiv I maybe?

Tags: verb, subjunctive, conjugation

So, I was listening to the Langsam gesprochene Nachrichten Podcast by DW, and the following was said (my own transcription):

> Außenminister Frank Walter Steinmeier hat sich betroffen über die Situation der Flüchtlinge an der Grenze zwischen Griechenland und Mazedonien geäußert. Sie **zeige**, dass nationale Schritte die Flüchtlingskrise nicht lösen könnten, sagte Steinmeier der Deutschen Welle... (u.s.w).

The first sentence is given for context. 
My question is the following: Why is the word "zeige" used? If "Sie" refers to the Flüchtlingskrise (fem), then shouldn't it be zeigt?
If this is using reported speech, in which case 3rd pers. sing. is zeige, can Konjunktiv I be used like that?

PS. This is from "Langsam Gesprochene Nachrichten" for 3.1.2016.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 9):

That sentence contains indirekte Rede (engl.: reported speech). That requires to use the Konjunktiv I. And the "sie" refers to "Situation der Flüchtlinge".

You will encounter such forms quite often when you listen to news.

Comment: This answer seems to make your identical comment obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

»Sie« refers to the accusative object from the first sentence, which is

> die Situation der Flüchtlinge an der Grenze zwischen Griechenland und Mazedonien

This object contains two attributive additions (»der Flüchtlinge« and »an der Grenze zwischen Griechenland und Mazedonien«) which can be omitted if we replace the pronoun »sie« by the phrase it stands for. So the second sentence can be thought as:

> *Die Situation **zeige**, dass nationale Schritte die Flüchtlingskrise nicht lösen könnten*, sagte Steinmeier der Deutschen Welle.

The part of this sentence, that is marked in italics, is indirect speech. Direct speech is marked with quotation marks:

> „Die Situation **zeigt**, dass nationale Schritte die Flüchtlingskrise nicht lösen könnten“ sagte Steinmeier der Deutschen Welle.

I used German standard quotation marks (**„x“**) in my example above, but you might have noticed, that I normally use chevrons (**»x«**), which are allowed in German too. Note, that German quotation marks (**„x“**) are different from English quotation marks (American English: **“x”**, British English: **‘x’**).

---

Indirect speech is not marked with special characters. The way how indirect speech is marked in German, is by a grammatical chance: You have to use *Konjunktiv I* where *Indikativ* was used in the text that was originally said.

> *Indikativ*: Die Situation *zeigt*, dass ...
>   *Konjunktiv I*: Die Situation *zeige*, dass ...

But there also other ways to show that you have indirect speech. I'll show this on two simpler examples:

- direkte Rede

  - in Anführungszeichen

    > 1. Roland sagt: »Das Taxi fährt zu schnell.«
    > 2. Der Angeklagte behauptet: »Ich habe ihn nicht erschossen.«
- indirekte Rede

  - Konjunktiv I

    > 1. Roland sagt, das Taxi fahre zu schnell.
    > 2. Der Angeklagte behauptet, er habe ihn nicht erschossen.
    >      <sup>(Note the change of the personal pronoun because of a different speaker!)</sup>
  - "würde" + Infinitiv

    > 1. Roland sagt, das Taxi würde zu schnell fahren.
    > 2. Der Angeklagte behauptet, er würde ihn nicht erschossen haben.
  - Nebensatz mit Indikativ

    > 1. Roland sagt, dass das Taxi zu schnell fährt.
    > 2. Der Angeklagte behauptet, dass er ihn nicht erschossen hat.
  - Nebensatz mit Konjunktiv I

    > 1. Roland sagt, dass das Taxi zu schnell fahre.
    > 2. Der Angeklagte behauptet, dass er ihn nicht erschossen habe.
  - Nebensatz mit Indikativ + "würde"

    > 1. Roland sagt, dass das Taxi zu schnell fahren würde.
    > 2. -
  - »zu« + Infinitiv

    > 1. -
    > 2. Der Angeklagte behauptet, ihn nicht erschossen zu haben.
  - Modalverb

    > 1. -
    > 2. Der Angeklagte will ihn nicht erschossen haben.
  - Als Quellenangabe

    > 1. Gemäß Rolands Behauptung fuhr das Taxi zu schnell.
    > 2. Laut seiner eigenen Aussage hat der Angeklagte ihn nicht erschossen.

As you can see from my examples, not all ways of constructing indirect speech are always possible.

Please note, that not all ways that I've listed here are called »indirekte Rede« in grammar books. Some of them are *Ersatzkonstruktionen* (*replacements*), but they all express, that someone has said something without directly quoting the speakers words.

Comment: Ersetzt *würde* nicht eigentlich den Konjunktiv II?

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I understand now. I had ALWAYS been given examples of Konjunctive I reported speech as "er sagt, er liebe mich" and other things beginning explicitly with "er sagt" or "er schreit" or whatever. This one, I know, has "er sagte" afterwards anyway, but it's nice to know how widely Konjunctiv I can be used

Answer (score 2):

Indeed,  Konjunktiv 1 for reported speech.

What Steinmeier originally said was: "Sie zeigt, dass..."